# LUA unexpected symbol near ')' line local society =

Tags: lua, fivem

```
RegisterServerEvent('esx_society:depositMoney')
AddEventHandler('esx_society:depositMoney', function(society, amount)

  local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
  local society = 'society_mechanic', function(society)

  if amount > 0 and xPlayer.get('money') >= amount then

    TriggerEvent('esx_addonaccount:getSharedAccount', society.account, function(account)
      xPlayer.removeMoney(amount)
      account.addMoney(amount)
    end)

    TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', xPlayer.source, _U('have_deposited', amount))

  else
    TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', xPlayer.source, _U('invalid_amount'))
  end

end)
```

Hello, an error appears in my console when i use script.
Where can the error come from?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error with your function `local society = 'society_mechanic', function(society)` => `end` missing.

Correct your code like this :

```lua
RegisterServerEvent('esx_society:depositMoney')
AddEventHandler('esx_society:depositMoney', function(society, amount)

  local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
  local society = 'society_mechanic', function(society)

  if amount > 0 and xPlayer.get('money') >= amount then

    TriggerEvent('esx_addonaccount:getSharedAccount', society.account, function(account)
      xPlayer.removeMoney(amount)
      account.addMoney(amount)
    end)

    TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', xPlayer.source, _U('have_deposited', amount))

  else
    TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', xPlayer.source, _U('invalid_amount'))
  end

  end

end)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code is a `end` missing. You open a function in `local society` but doesn't close it.